# Identify items in hash with matching and non-matching criteria

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, matching

I have two tab-delimited files:
one is a reference with thousands of entries
and the other is a list of millions of criteria
that are used to search the reference.

I make a hash of the reference file with the following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#use Data::Dumper;
#use Timer::Runtime;

use feature qw( say );

my $in_qfn          = $ARGV[0];
my $out_qfn         = $ARGV[1];
my $transcripts_qfn = "file";

my %transcripts;

{
   open(my $transcripts_fh, "<", $transcripts_qfn)
      or die("Can't open \"$transcripts_qfn\": $!\n");

   while ( <$transcripts_fh> ) {
      chomp;
      my @refs = split(/\t/, $_);
      my ($ref_chr, $ref_strand) = @refs[0, 6];
      my $values =  {
         start => $refs[3],
         end   => $refs[4],
         info  => $refs[8]
      };

      #print Data::Dumper->Dump([$values]), $/; #confirm structure is fine
      push @{ $transcripts{$ref_chr}{$ref_strand} }, $values;
   }  
}
```

Then I open the other input file, define the elements, and parse the hash to find matching criteria

```
while ( <$in_fh> ) {
  chomp;
  my ($x, $strand, $chr, $y, $z) = split(/\t/, $_);

  #match the reference hash for things equal to $chr and $strand
  my $transcripts_array = $transcripts{$chr}{$strand};

  for my $transcript ( @$transcripts_array ) {
     my $start = $transcript->{start};
     my $end   = $transcript->{end};
     my $info  = $transcript->{info};

     #print $info and other criteria from if statements to outfile, this code works
  }
}
```

This works, but I would like to know if I can then find elements in the hash that match `$chr` but not `$strand` (which has a binary value of either sign).

I put the following into the same `while` block after the previous `for`, but it does not appear to work

```
my $transcripts_opposite_strand = $transcripts{$chr}{!$strand};

for my $transcript (@$transcripts_opposite_strand) {

   my $start = $transcript->{start};
   my $end   = $transcript->{end};
   my $info  = $transcript->{info};

   #print $info and other criteria from if statements
}
```

I apologize for the code snippets; I tried to keep the relevant information.   Because of the size of the files I can't really brute force it by going line by line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation operator `!` enforces boolean context on its argument. `"+"` and `"-"` are both true in boolean context, so `! $strand` is always false, i.e. `""` in string context.

Either store boolean value in the hash

```
$strand = $strand eq '+';
```

or don't use boolean negation:

```
my $transcripts_opposite_strand = $transripts{$chr}{ $strand eq '+' ? '-' : '+' };
```

The ternary operator can be replaced by a shorter but less readable alternatives, e.g.

```
   qw( + - )[ $strand eq '+' ]
```

because in numeric context, true is interpreted as 1 and false as 0.

Comment: I used the second suggestion of ignoring boolean negation and the script works.  Cheers.